# Add key to dictionary within list of dictionaries based on value of another dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary within a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
input = [{'Clause':'Text that describes clause 1', 'Source':'pdf_file', 'additional_info': {'State_Index':0, 'City_Index':0, 'Population':100}},
        {'Clause':'Text that describes clause 2', 'Source':'pdf_file', 'additional_info': {'State_Index':0, 'City_Index':1, 'Population':150}},
        {'Clause':'Text that describes clause 3', 'Source':'pdf_file', 'additional_info': {'State_Index':1, 'City_Index':0, 'Population':75}},
        {'Clause':'Text that describes clause 4', 'Source':'pdf_file', 'additional_info': {'State_Index':1, 'City_Index':1, 'Population':20}}]
```

Basically, I have text of clauses and each clause is specific to a city/state combo, detailed within the second dictionary. The first dictionary captures the clause, source, and the second additional_info dictionary. Within the additional_info dictionary we capture some more information. Separately, I have the name of each state and city corresponding to their index. What I'd like to do is simply add `'State_Name'` to the additional_info dictionary with the name that corresponds to the `'State_Index'`. The index looks like this:

```
| State_Index | State_Name     |
| ----------- | -------------- |
| 0           | AL             |
| 1           | AK             |
| .           | .              |
| .           | .              |
| .           | .              |
| 49          | WY             |
```

So the additional_info dictionary would then include whichever state name corresponds to the index listed in the dictionary.

I am having some trouble on where to even begin for this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I have the name of each state and city corresponding to their index`. In what data structure? Is it a csv file? a dictionary? a pandas dataframe?

Comment: The table right underneath shows the structure. It is a pandas df but can be converted to whatever the best format is for this task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote

```
input = [ ... ]
```

but that's not great, as it shadows the
[input()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)
builtin. Prefer to conventionally append an `_` underscore
so we have a distinct identifier:

```
input_ = [ ... ]
```

Or perhaps pluralize it.

---

[Read in](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader)
a dictionary with the desired mapping:

```
import csv
...
    with open('states.csv') as f:
        sheet = csv.DictReader(f)
        idx_to_name = {int(row['State_Index']): row['State_Name']
                       for row in sheet}
```

With that datastructure in hand, the task becomes easy.

```
    verbose = True

    for row in input_:
        info: dict = row['additional_info']
        idx: int = info['State_Index']

        info['State_Name'] = idx_to_name[idx]

        assert len(info) == 4
        if verbose:
            print(info)
```